# web essentials browser link not working in asp mvc 6 project

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, browser-link

I'm trying to get browser link working so I can use web essentials toolbar in the browser. I'd expect to see some code injected at the bottom of the page source for browser link like in ASP.NET 4 projects but this doesnt seem to be the case with ASP.NET 5.

[image]

Has anyone else managed to get this working? Thanks in advanced for any help.

I'm using visual studio 2015 update 1

I've tried running in admin mode and I've turned firewall off but still no connections in browser link in visual studio when running in debug mode.

**Edit**

This method is definitely being called

```
app.UseBrowserLink();
```

This nuget package is definitely refereced `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader`

I've tried re-installing asp.net 5 rc1 and visual studio 2015 pro as well as using visual studio community which doesnt work either.

Ive tried reinstalling IIS Express 10 and 8 which also doesn't work.

This is beginning to be a real pain. Using the F12 in the browser does the job but its really slow and tedious

if anyone can provide a suggestion of something to try to get this working that would be great. I feel i've exhausted all options.

Here is my project.json:

```
{
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-BusiHub.Web-ce0683d8-2598-4feb-99b6-82d6cf4e8028",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Loader.IIS.Interop": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final",
    "System.Web.Optimization.Less": "1.3.4"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": { }
    }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],

  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Here is my startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Set up configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
            builder.AddUserSecrets();
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();

        services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContextInitializer>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ApplicationDbContextInitializer dbContextInitializer)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            // Allow updates to your files in Visual Studio to be shown in the browser. You can use the Refresh 
            // browser link button in the Visual Studio toolbar or Ctrl+Alt+Enter to refresh the browser.
            app.UseBrowserLink();

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

            // For more details on creating database during deployment see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615859
            try
            {
                using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                    .CreateScope())
                {
                    serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>()
                         .Database.Migrate();
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        app.UseIISPlatformHandler(options => options.AuthenticationDescriptions.Clear());

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentity();

        // To configure external authentication please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        // Seed the database with sample data - admin roles, admin users etc
        await dbContextInitializer.InitializeDataAsync();
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```

**Update**

I've installed livereload plugin for chrome and configured livereload in gulp as suggested in comment below by vendettamit. Chrome browser is now updating when I modify my CSS/Less files. I'm still lacking the web essentials design and inspect tools due to browser link not working but I hope this will change in future updates to ASP.NET framework and/or visual studio.

my script for gulp if anyone stumbles across this same issue:

```
    /// <binding BeforeBuild='min, less' Clean='clean' />
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp"),
    rimraf = require("rimraf"),
    concat = require("gulp-concat"),
    cssmin = require("gulp-cssmin"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
    less = require("gulp-less"),
    livereload = require("gulp-livereload");

var project = require('./project.json');

var paths = {
    webroot: "./wwwroot/"
};

paths.js = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.js";
paths.minJs = paths.webroot + "js/**/*.min.js";
paths.css = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.css";
paths.minCss = paths.webroot + "css/**/*.min.css";
paths.concatJsDest = paths.webroot + "js/site.min.js";
paths.concatCssDest = paths.webroot + "css/site.min.css";

gulp.task("clean:js", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.webroot + "/js/site.min.js", cb);
    rimraf(paths.webroot + "/js/site.js", cb);
});

gulp.task("clean:css", function (cb) {
    rimraf(paths.webroot + "/css/site.min.css", cb);
    rimraf(paths.webroot + "/css/site.css", cb);
});

gulp.task("clean", ["clean:js", "clean:css"]);

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.js, "!" + paths.minJs], { base: "." })
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatJsDest))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min:css", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.css, "!" + paths.minCss])
        .pipe(concat(paths.concatCssDest))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});

gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:css"]);

gulp.task("less", ["clean:css"], function () {
    return gulp.src('Styles/*.less')
        .pipe(concat('site.less'))
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + '/css'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});

gulp.task("scripts", ["clean:js"], function() {
    return gulp.src('Scripts/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('site.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + '/js'));
});

gulp.task("all", ["less", "scripts"]);

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    livereload.listen();
    gulp.watch('styles/*less', ['less']);
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if Live reload is shipped with RC version. There was an [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/213) addressed similar problem with Browser link. Mean while you can try [this](https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload)

Comment: You can also try the given solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034169/live-reload-with-asp-net-5) but looks like it's manual refresh.

Comment: Thanks, ill definitely try and get that set up. It would be a lot faster than using the F12 window. The reason i like using web essentials is because of the design and inspect on the toolbar which requires a connection on browser link. For some reason i can't get this to work?

Comment: @vendettamit if you post this as an answer i will mark it as correct. I think the browser link is an issue with the asp.net 5 framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Live reload is shipped with RC version. There was an issue addressed similar problem with Browser link. Mean while you can try [this](https://github.com/vohof/gulp-livereload) chrome plugin for live reload.

You can also try the given solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034169/live-reload-with-asp-net-5) but looks like it's manual refresh.