# Enable Browser Link in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, browser, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-code, shortcut

I would like to know if there is any Visual Studio Code extension for Enabling Browser Link DashBoard like in Visual Studio. I have been searching without luck, I just see result for debug. I miss open 5 windows, make a change and then ctrl + alt + Enter,  refresh the five. Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: For small projects I solved importing live.js (http://livejs.com/) in my html views.

Comment: Same issue here. I added BrowserLink (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33034275) but seems not to work. Maybe this is because the related setting which I know from Visual Studio seems missing in Visual Studio Core.

Answer (score 0):

Install Microsoft Extension `Live Preview` for VS Code, after installing and restarting the VS Code right click on the `.html` file and click `Show Preview` it will open the file in VS Code for preview and any changes to CSS will be updated to preview just like while using Visual Studio `Browser Link` if you want to open it in a separate browser like Chrome just copy the link and open it in any browser.

Answer (score 0):

today hot reload is available throught:
dotnet watch --project [projectname]

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-watch