# local live server for Asp.Net application, to view live changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am new to the asp.net MVC concept and project design, i'm at early learning stage.

i'm using **visual studio 2019** | project type : **asp.net MVC (.net framework)**

i want to know how to deploy my application for viewing live-changes, like there is an with node.js live-server extension we can use (localhost:8080) to track live changes in html,css,js whenever we save these file browser automatically reloads and we can see the changes.

how can i do it for the asp.net MVC application as it has such complex architecture?

if  i run the IIS Express which is default, it does not automatically reloads when content changes, file is saved and it open the visual studio debugging mode which is pretty annoying to work with.

> there are extension like BrowserLinkLivePreview but it does not auto
> reloads the main page (index.html) when any of the file's code is changed and
> saved.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Live reload with Asp.Net 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33034169/live-reload-with-asp-net-5)

Comment: no both the answer did not help in auto reload of the browser, i still have to click the reload manually.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this tool:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BrowserReloadonSave. It works on VS 2019 Community.

You can see here how to set up Browser Link in ASP.NET Core ("You can use Browser Link to refresh your web app in several browsers at once..."):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-browserlink?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Browser Link setup:

Add the **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink** package to your project. For ASP.NET Core Razor Pages or MVC projects, also enable runtime compilation of Razor (.cshtml) files as described in Razor file compilation in ASP.NET Core. Razor syntax changes are applied only when runtime compilation has been enabled.

Configuration:

Call UseBrowserLink in the Startup. Configure method:

**app.UseBrowserLink();**

The UseBrowserLink call is typically placed inside an if block that only enables Browser Link in the Development environment. For example:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())    
{    
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();    
    app.UseBrowserLink();    
}
```

Comment: tried it, does not auto reload the page when i make changes in (eg. index.cshtml) and save.

Answer (score 0):

I add temporarily javascript in `cshtml` to reload every few seconds, since no

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 4000);
</script>
```